# How to add JavaScript to input field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this input field in Rails 3.1:

```
<%=f.file_field :image, :id => "upload"%>
```

I want to add this JavaScript before the input field:

```
onchange="readURL(this);
```

How can I do this?

Must see in HTML sth like:

```
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this); name="post[image]" id="upload">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using JQuery?

```
$("#upload").change(function() { 
  ..
});
```

is one way and

```
$("#upload").bind("change", function() {
  ..
});
```

is another.

[JQuery Doc.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

***Update:***

You can write it as:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, :id => "upload", :onchange => "readURL(this)" %>
```

This will give you HTML something like:

```
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this); return false;" name="post[image]" id="upload">
```

Comment: its good, but how can I add `onchange="readURL(this);` inside jquery code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this is via unobtrusive JavaScript (essentially adding JavaScript functionality to a page after the DOM is loaded, and making it optional).  In rails 3.1 and later, you want to add the JS code in Syed's answer to `app/assets/javascript/controller_name.js.coffee` or similiar.

Comment: Thank you Kyle I will do with unobtrusive Javascript :D